# Applying general relativity to quantum particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity

Can one reach accurate conclusions about subatomic particles by applying general relativity to them?

As a non-example of an "accurate conclusion," one wouldn't assume a vacuum when attempting to calculate the trajectory of an object in a highly viscous fluid.  Would using general relativity to characterize the motions and/or interactions of subatomic particles produce similarly incorrect results?  Could any meaningful insights be extracted?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is probably not general relativity. And probably yes quantum gravity. Unfortunately we do not yet have a valid and confirmed theory of quantum gravity, and very little data on what it might entail, but we do know that at high enough energies (more than a trillion times higher than what we are able to experiment with at LHC), elementary particle physics as we know it today (let's call it QT, for quantum theory, and today's standard model is called that, the standard model (SM)), cannot explain certain things, and is expected will not work at much higher energies than what we can generate at the LHC.

The SM is a quantum field theory, and it accounts for all the particles we've observed, but has no answer on certain issues that we know are there but are not yet understood like dark matter and dark energy, the tiny mass of the neutrino, etc). It will not work at those higher energies. There is strong evidence that there will need to be something beyond the SM, I.e., a yet unknown BSM. It also does not account for gravity, and does not seem to be able to be made compatible with general relativity.

General Relativity seems to be able to explain gravity, within certain limits. Within those limits it has no effect on QT or elementary particles. But it is believed, on strong theoretical grounds, that at the so called Planck energy (more than trillions of times more than the LHC) the gravitational force on elementary particles (with each other) is of about the same magnitude as the other 3 forces. Even more, that at those energies the sizes involved, called Planck sizes (about $10^{-33}$ cm), orders of magnitude smaller than electrons or quarks, spacetime has to be quantized, and the smooth continuum spacetime of General relativity cannot exist. More, that particles are not particles at that point, and that QT as we know it cannot work.

Thus, at the Planck scales General relativity and QT must become one, and different than either. That is what is called a theory of quantum gravity, QG.

There are a few attempts at a theory of QG, none validated at this point. String or Superstring or M Theory is one set, loop quantum gravity another, and there's probably a few others, less well known. At those sizes gravity has an effect on elementary 'particles', which are no longer particles then. In string theory they are strings and branes. Quarks and electrons don't exist at those sizes. The QT vacuum in a curved spacetime, if the curved spacetime is curved enough, need a QG theory. (You can extrapolate some and treat a quantum vacuum, with all its fluctuations, in a curved spacetime, as long as the curvature is not so strong that one must look at sizes like the Planck sizes.)

Now, you would then think we can worry about that when we reach those large energy values -- it would take an accelerator the size of the solar system to create those energies, theoretically. So, it'll be along while. But, it also turns out that there are things we can observe, from astrophysics and cosmology, that reaches those energy levels. The Big Bang and the first fractions of a sec of the universe, and Black Holes, reach those energy levels. The early universe is when the first particles of the universe were made, and before that strings or loops if they are real. And we can explore some of that by observing the remnants of all of that, such as the cosmic microwave radiation, the CMB, and other features of the universe. Similarly for black holes, gravitational radiation from them when they form or merge gives us a window into very high energy physics.

So, there is some active work on theoretically unifying gravity, or General relativity, and QT (as in string theory), and there are ongoing efforts to try to determine more about black holes, dark matter, early universe exotic particles not yet discovered, dark energy, the spacetime in the early life of the universe, and other astrophysical or cosmological connections of QT and General relativity. Also work at accelerators like LHC to get more experimental results in the hope of discovering new particles or new physics that would lead to the BSM. We have, in both General relativity and QT, more theories than observations or experiments. Probably worse for QG than for BSM.

The next 10 years will tell us something new, or will lead to a deep search for where are we going totally wrong. Gravity and General relativity, and QT for elementary particles, are at the center of the issue.

See an intro to QG at wikipedia's article on Quantum Gravity (I tried to paste it her but it won't. Just google Quantum Gravity and the wiki article is the first one typically). For Physics Beyond the Standard Model 
do the same.

Comment: +1 very nice summary, I don't know if Penrose twister theory ever really got going. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twistor_theory

Comment: Thanks. Twistors, slowed down in the 70's, the Witten noted in a paper that it could work and be used to calculate more easily amplitudes in a Twistor String Theory. Google it. Still, I don't see much of it in GR or quantum gravity or Strings. Oxford Mathematics has a page and some things on it, with some people listed as doing something or interested. And every once in a while when somebody wants to confuse everybody else they'll bring it up (yes, exaggerating).

Answer (score 0):

> Can one reach accurate conclusions about subatomic particles by applying general relativity to them?

No, to the best of my absolutely non expert knowledge, we cannot,  but it **might** apply the other way around if we can achieve a fusion of the two theories, called quantum gravity.

General Relativity is a classical theory, so it does not incorporate any major ideas from quantum mechanics. Trying to understand quantum mechanics using classical physics (like GR) is like trying to follow your very first football game, when all you have is the rules of baseball.

Some things are superficially similar in both games/theories,  but most times you cannot apply the rules of one theory to the other.

> As a non-example of an "accurate conclusion," one wouldn't assume a vacuum when attempting to calculate the trajectory of an object in a highly viscous fluid. Would using general relativity to characterize the motions and/or interactions of subatomic particles produce similarly incorrect results? Could any meaningful insights be extracted?

The real world is ruled by quantum mechanics, not by classical mechanics, which is an approximation. Most of the time we can use classical mechanics, so we can easily "get away" with using Newtons 400 year old laws to precisely  land a Mars rover, but we could not design an integrated chip or an MRI scanner, without using quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is basically asking if there is a mathematical physics link between general relativity and quantum physics. But there is no widely accepted theory by physicists that unites the two. Its still a famous open problem in physics to unify these two pillars of 20th century physics.